# kubernetes "unable to get metrics"

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, autoscaling, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I am trying to autoscale a deployment and a statefulset, by running respectivly these two commands:

```
kubectl autoscale statefulset mysql --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10
kubectl expose deployment frontend --type=LoadBalancer --name=frontend
```

Sadly, on the minikube dashboard, this error appears under both services:

```
failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server could not find the requested resource (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
```

Searching online I read that it might be a dns error, so I checked but CoreDNS seems to be running fine.
Both workloads are nothing special, this is the 'frontend' deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: frontend
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: hubuser/repo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, could you please verify if the API is working fine? To do so, please run `kubectl get --raw /apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1`.

If you get an error similar to:

“`Error from server (NotFound)`:”

Please follow these steps:

1.- Remove all the proxy environment variables from the kube-apiserver manifest.

2.- In the kube-controller-manager-amd64, set `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-use-rest-clients=false`

3.- The last scenario is that your metric-server add-on is disabled by default. You can verify it by using:

$ minikube addons list

If it is disabled, you will see something like `metrics-server: disabled`.

You can enable it by using:

```
$minikube addons enable metrics-server
```

When it is done, delete and recreate your HPA.

You can use the following [thread](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/41) as a reference.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, the output I get seems alright: `{"kind":"APIResourceList","apiVersion":"v1","groupVersion":"metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1","resources":[{"name":"nodes","singularName":"","namespaced":false,"kind":"NodeMetrics","verbs":["get","list"]},{"name":"pods","singularName":"","nam
espaced":true,"kind":"PodMetrics","verbs":["get","list"]}]}
`

Comment: Then follow the other steps I listed for you and visit the URL I gave you, please let us know the result.

Comment: Hi @gijoyah, were you able to follow the final steps?